# How to change my custom error html from rendering itself twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When I try to create a category by using Ajax I get a strange behavior with my error message.

Right now I have my error message appearing like this:

[image]

My create.js.erb and new.js.erb both have the same code which is just this line:

```
$(".cc-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'categories/form', locals: { category: @category })) %>");
```

This is my category form:

```
<%= form_for(@category, :remote => true, :html => { :class => "add-form", :id => "cform" }) do |f| %>
<fieldset>
   <p>
      <%= f.label :name, "Category Name *" %>
      <br />
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
   </p>
   <div class="form-actions">
     <%= f.submit "Create" %>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

Here is the code to enable custom error HTML:

```
# application.rb

ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
   errors = Array(instance.error_message).join(',')
   %(#{html_tag}<span class="validation-error">&nbsp;#{errors}</span>).html_safe
end
```

Then the HTML itself along with the error HTML:

```
<p>
  <label for="category_name">Category Name *</label><span class="validation-error">&nbsp;can't be blank</span>
  <br>
  <input id="category_name" name="category[name]" size="30" type="text" value=""><span class="validation-error">&nbsp;can't be blank</span>
</p>
```

I only want the error message next to the `label` and not the right side of the `input`. How would I do this? The format is tricky for me when I look at it.

Thanks.

Comment: And how does your categories/form partial look?

Comment: @Dogbert There you go. I posted it.

Comment: You might have accidentally included jQuery twice.

Comment: @BenjaminTan The Error message works fine without changes though. When I went to this particular custom HTML is when the nonsense started. Thanks, just in case I did check my application.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use `field_error_proc` badly, because it's good to wrap the input field into element with special class. `Field_error_proc` tags both the label and input tag with `field_with_error` by default since the refered object (`:name` that means `category.name` having the errors array) is the same. It's not a defect, because it's good for changing your label's color to red in this case. I checked the Rails code (`actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/label.rb`) and you can't turn this behavior off for labels (it can be a feature request), so I guess there's only one solution for your problem if you use plain html for labels.

I have two solutions now for your problem:

- Instead of

  ```
  <%= f.label :name, "Category Name *" %>
  ```

  use

  ```
  <label for="category_name">Category Name *</label>
  ```

  in your view.
- It's not too nice, but you can use `f.label` if you make `form .label .validation-error { display: none }` in your stylesheet file. I know it's just a workaround, but if `f.label` is necessary, then I don't know better solution.

Comment: Or you can check the html tag in your field_error_proc like in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023548/overriding-actionviewbase-field-error-proc-in-refinerycms

Answer (score 0):

You have two of these `<span>` tags in the page:

```
<span class="validation-error">&nbsp;can't be blank</span>
```

EDIT:

Okay, it looks like both the label and the input need to be wrapped with a custom error. Here are a couple of links:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t](https://gist.github.com/1464315)

https://gist.github.com/1464315

Comment: That's how it renders it. How do I change up the error html to only do it by the label? The error html is confusing to me.

Comment: Could you not remove the 2nd <span> tag? Because you have two of the same exact spans they are both affected with any changes that your javascript and/or css make to them. You'd have to give them different ID's or classes.

Comment: Oh wait, I see. Rails is rendering two of those tags for you. Is that correct?